# FTP client can not be resolved in felix

Tags: maven, maven-2, osgi, ftp-client, apache-felix

I am facing a problem that org.apache.commons.net.ftp.ftpclient cannot be resolved when bundle is deployed to the Felix console. I have added a maven dependency also in the pom. But didn't get how can i solve this issue.

Because of this bundle is in installed state and not coming to Active state.

Any suggestions really appreciable.

Comment: If the bundle is not started, check the log file to see any exceptions which have prevented it from starting.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have solved the issue by first converting the commons-net.jar to bundle and then adding it to the apache felix console. Actually the problem was that it does not have the package in Apache console so i have manually added it.

Comment: great! You should add this as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Robert. 
Solution
 I have solved the issue by first converting the commons-net.jar to bundle and then adding it to the apache felix console. Actually the problem was that it does not have the package in Apache console so i have manually added it